# Can't access React app from localhost (MAMP)

Tags: reactjs, mamp, react-router-dom

I create a React app, this is my `route` :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import BonusScreen from './BonusScreen';
import HistoryBonus from './HistoryBonus';

// store all the routes
export default () => (
<BrowserRouter basename={"/api"}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/bonus/:id" exact component={BonusScreen}/>
        <Route path="/historyBonus" exact component={HistoryBonus}/>
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
);
```

then I run `npm run build`, after that I moved the build files into my `htdocs`

I tried to access it in my browser like this :

> http://localhost:8888/api/bonus/NGO628567652201

but it always return

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /api/bonus/NGO628567652201 was not found on this server.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: On which port react and API are running

Comment: the API is running on different server (online), I access the react app on `:8888`

Comment: Then this is not right API url.correct is wit base url

Comment: I access it `localhost:8888/api/bonus/NGO628567652201`. api is my base url, bonus/NGO628567652201 is route path as you can see on my question...can't fix it since yesterday

Comment: Is it giving any response?

Comment: always return 404